# Issue with Hash using clang llvm3.6 command line tools on Mac OS X

Tags: c++, macos, hash

Having issues compiling this header file provided by Bjourne Stroustrup and edited by my professor. I'm compiling on OS X 10.10.2 using command line tools. My compile command is " gcc -std=C++11 *cpp" and there is something about this code it just doesn't like. I ran this on Linux and my university's Unix server without issues. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I'll include the header file and then the error.

```
/*std_lib_facilities_4.h
Minimally revised for C++11 features of GCC 4.6.3 or later
Walter C. Daugherity        June 10, 2012 and January 9, 2014
*/

/*
simple "Programming: Principles and Practice using C++" course header to
be used for the first few weeks.
It provides the most common standard headers (in the global namespace)
and minimal exception/error support.

Students: please don't try to understand the details of headers just yet.
All will be explained. This header is primarily used so that you don't have
to understand every concept all at once.

Revised April 25, 2010: simple_error() added
*/

#ifndef H112
#define H112 201401L

#define GCC_VERSION (__GNUC__*10000 + __GNUC_MINOR__*100 + __GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__)

#if GCC_VERSION >= 40603
//New C++11 headers in GCC 4.6.3 or later
#include <array>
#include <regex>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <forward_list>
#include <ratio>
#include <tuple>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>
#endif

#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<sstream>
#include<cmath>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<string>
#include<list>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<stdexcept>

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#if GCC_VERSION >= 40603
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>
#else
#define unordered_map hash_map
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#include <hash_map>
using stdext::hash_map;
#else
#include <ext/hash_map>
using __gnu_cxx::hash_map;

namespace __gnu_cxx {

    template<> struct hash<std::string>
    {
        size_t operator()(const std::string& s) const
        {
            return hash<char*>()(s.c_str());
        }
    };

} // of namespace __gnu_cxx
#endif //_MSC_VER
#endif //GCC_VERSION >= 40603

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

typedef long Unicode;

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using namespace std;

template<class T> string to_string(const T& t)
{
    ostringstream os;
    os << t;
    return os.str();
}

struct Range_error : out_of_range { // enhanced vector range error reporting
    int index;
    Range_error(int i) :out_of_range("Range error: " + to_string(i)), index(i) { }
};


// trivially range-checked vector (no iterator checking):
template< class T> struct Vector : public std::vector<T> {
    typedef typename std::vector<T>::size_type size_type;

    Vector() { }
    explicit Vector(size_type n) :std::vector<T>(n) {}
    Vector(size_type n, const T& v) :std::vector<T>(n, v) {}
    template <class I>
    Vector(I first, I last) : std::vector<T>(first, last) {}
#if GCC_VERSION >= 40603
    Vector(initializer_list<T> list) : std::vector<T>(list) {}
#endif

    T& operator[](unsigned int i) // rather than return at(i);
    {
        if (this->size() <= i) throw Range_error(i);
        return std::vector<T>::operator[](i);
    }
    const T& operator[](unsigned int i) const
    {
        if (this->size() <= i) throw Range_error(i);
        return std::vector<T>::operator[](i);
    }
};

// disgusting macro hack to get a range checked vector:
#define vector Vector

// trivially range-checked string (no iterator checking):
struct String : std::string {

    String() { }
    String(const char* p) :std::string(p) {}
    String(const string& s) :std::string(s) {}
    template<class S> String(S s) : std::string(s) {}
    String(int sz, char val) :std::string(sz, val) {}
    template<class Iter> String(Iter p1, Iter p2) : std::string(p1, p2) { }

    char& operator[](unsigned int i) // rather than return at(i);
    {
        if (size() <= i) throw Range_error(i);
        return std::string::operator[](i);
    }

    const char& operator[](unsigned int i) const
    {
        if (size() <= i) throw Range_error(i);
        return std::string::operator[](i);
    }
};

#ifndef _MSC_VER
#if GCC_VERSION >= 40603
namespace std {

    template<> struct hash<String>
    {
        size_t operator()(const String& s) const
        {
            return hash<std::string>()(s);
        }
    };

} // of namespace std
#else
namespace __gnu_cxx {

    template<> struct hash<String>
    {
        size_t operator()(const String& s) const
        {
            return hash<std::string>()(s);
        }
    };

} // of namespace __gnu_cxx
#endif //GCC_VERSION >= 40603
#endif //_MSC_VER


struct Exit : runtime_error {
    Exit() : runtime_error("Exit") {}
};

// error() simply disguises throws:
inline void error(const string& s)
{
    throw runtime_error(s);
}

inline void error(const string& s, const string& s2)
{
    error(s + s2);
}

inline void error(const string& s, int i)
{
    ostringstream os;
    os << s << ": " << i;
    error(os.str());
}

#if _MSC_VER<1500
// disgusting macro hack to get a range checked string:
#define string String
// MS C++ 9.0 have a built-in assert for string range check
// and uses "std::string" in several places so that macro substitution fails
#endif

template<class T> char* as_bytes(T& i)  // needed for binary I/O
{
    void* addr = &i;    // get the address of the first byte
    // of memory used to store the object
    return static_cast<char*>(addr); // treat that memory as bytes
}


inline void keep_window_open()
{
    cin.clear();
    cout << "Please enter a character to exit\n";
    char ch;
    cin >> ch;
    return;
}

inline void keep_window_open(string s)
{
    if (s == "") return;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(120, '\n');
    for (;;) {
        cout << "Please enter " << s << " to exit\n";
        string ss;
        while (cin >> ss && ss != s)
            cout << "Please enter " << s << " to exit\n";
        return;
    }
}



// error function to be used (only) until error() is introduced in Chapter 5:
inline void simple_error(string s)  // write ``error: s and exit program
{
    cerr << "error: " << s << '\n';
    keep_window_open();     // for some Windows environments
    exit(1);
}

// make std::min() and std::max() accessible:
#undef min
#undef max

#include<iomanip>
inline ios_base& general(ios_base& b)   // to augment fixed and scientific
{
    b.setf(ios_base::fmtflags(0), ios_base::floatfield);
    return b;
}

// run-time checked narrowing cast (type conversion):
template<class R, class A> R narrow_cast(const A& a)
{
    R r = R(a);
    if (A(r) != a) error(string("info loss"));
    return r;
}


inline int randint(int max) { return rand() % max; }

inline int randint(int min, int max) { return randint(max - min) + min; }

inline double sqrt(int x) { return sqrt(double(x)); }   // to match C++0x

#endif //H112
```

Below is the Error

```
./std_lib_facilities.h:43:20: error: no matching function for call to object of
      type 'hash<char *>'
            return hash<char*>()(s.c_str());
```

Comment: It's not clear what compiler you are using.  Is it `gcc` or `clang`?  Is it Xcode or Macports?

Comment: The Apple XCode system provides a program `/usr/bin/gcc` which is not really GCC but is `clang` instead.  The version in XCode 6.3 claims its GCC version is 40201 using the formula in the code.  This may be throwing things off.  When I compile, one of the messages I get is "warning Use of the header `<ext/hash_map>` is deprecated.  Migrate to `<unordered_map>`".

Answer (score 3):

By way of an explanation for the odd-ball file names below, I have a script, `chkhdr++`, which checks whether a C++ header is compilable standalone, and whether it is idempotent.  It creates a 3-line source file such as `/tmp/chkhdr-95127.cpp` (the number is the process ID) that contains:

```
#include HEADER /* Check self-containment */
#include HEADER /* Check idempotency */
int main(void){return 0;}
```

and then compiles it, for example, with the command line:

```
 /usr/bin/g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -DHEADER=\"stdlibfacilities.h\" -c \
     /tmp/chkhdr-95127.cpp
```

When I compile the header from the question (named as `stdlibfacilities.h`) with `/usr/bin/g++` (which is the `g++` from XCode 6.3, which in turn is really `clang++`), I get the errors and warnings:

```
In file included from chkhdr-95127.cpp:1:
In file included from ./stdlibfacilities.h:59:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/ext/hash_map:212:5: warning: Use of
      the header <ext/hash_map> is deprecated. Migrate to <unordered_map> [-W#warnings]
#   warning Use of the header <ext/hash_map> is deprecated.  Migrate to <unordered_map>
    ^
In file included from chkhdr-95127.cpp:1:
./stdlibfacilities.h:68:20: error: no matching function for call to object of type 'hash<char *>'
            return hash<char*>()(s.c_str());
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/ext/__hash:38:12: note: candidate
      function not viable: 1st argument ('const value_type *' (aka 'const char *')) would lose const
      qualifier
    size_t operator()(char *__c) const _NOEXCEPT
           ^
1 warning and 1 error generated.
```

The note about a non-viable candidate function suggests a way around the problem — namely, replace the line:

```
return hash<char*>()(s.c_str());
```

with:

```
return hash<const char*>()(s.c_str());
```

That compilation gives:

```
In file included from chkhdr-95148.cpp:1:
In file included from ./stdlibfacilities.h:59:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/ext/hash_map:212:5: warning: Use of
      the header <ext/hash_map> is deprecated. Migrate to <unordered_map> [-W#warnings]
#   warning Use of the header <ext/hash_map> is deprecated.  Migrate to <unordered_map>
    ^
1 warning generated.
```

So, there is an easy fix for most of the trouble; add the missing `const`.  However, you should ideally migrate the header so it uses the standard `<unordered_map>` instead of `<ext/hash_map>`.